# Are there other places in Seville (Sevilla) to buy Alcázar tickets?

Tags: tickets, tips-and-tricks, seville

Today I visited the amazing Real Alcázar in Seville (Sevilla), which was well worth the waiting before I got in!

[image: From Nicolas Vollmer - Ambassadors Rooms - www.flickr.com/photos/nicolas_vollmer_photo/8282654227/]

However, when I got to the front of the queue, I discovered that the queue wasn't actually to get in, it was simply to buy tickets. People who already had tickets could walk down the left of the long queue, follow the sign to bypass the ticket office, and instead go straight to the turnstiles to enter the palace.

By the time I discovered this, it was too late for myself, as I'd already queued up at that point! However, I couldn't see anything explaining where the few lucky souls skipping the queue with their tickets had got them from...

Is there somewhere else in Seville where you can buy your tickets for the Real Alcázar, and thus avoid the huge queue for the ticket office at the palace itself?

[image: From Edward Dalmulder - Garden - www.flickr.com/photos/14635236@N04/4673881119/]

Answer (score 6):

[You can buy tickets in advance, online](http://www.alcazarsevilla.org/?p=129), from Seville or from any other place where you have internet access.

If you have a Sevilla Card [you can also bypass the queue](http://www.sevillacard.es/en/el-real-alcazar-de-sevilla).